# How can I call the JS function which is defined in subpage?

Tags: angularjs

In angularjs,I use the  directive to contains the subpage into mainpage.

However, I found when I want to call the JS function in subpage, the browser always return back the information .
I wonder what can I do to fixed the errors.

Mainpage

```
var menuModule = angular.module('menuModule',[]);
menuModule.controller("MenuSettingController", function($scope, $http) {
    initTree();
});
```

Subpage

`<script type="text/javascript">
    function initTree(){
        console.log("in");
    }
</script>`

Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you please provide the code snippet for this ?

Comment: You should use services in angular to share common logic between pages https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call a function which are defined in subpage, you can wrap it into the current `window` object. Moreover, you can also wrap object into your `window` object.

Then, you can call your function, into your **controllers** for example.

### Wrap function

**Controller**

```
(function(){

function Controller($scope) {

  initTree();

}

angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', Controller);

})();
```

**Subpage**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    (function(){

      function init(){
        console.log('init');
      }
      //Wrap our init function into our window object
      window.initTree = init;

    })();

  </script>
```

### Wrap object

But, as i said, you can wrap object to the `window` object, so you can do :

**Controller**

```
(function(){

function Controller($scope) {

  //Call our init function
  app_function.init();

  //Call our setter
  app_function.set(42);

}

angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', Controller);

})();
```

**Subpage**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    //initialize our anonymous function with the app_function or an empty object
    (function(app){

      function init(){
        console.log('init');
      }

      function set(n){
        console.log('Set value : ' + n);
      }

      //Register our function
      app.init = init;
      app.set = set;

    })(window.app_function = window.app_function || {});

  </script>
```

---

## Use angular services

Use angular services is a good practice, it will make your code more reusable and clean.

You have to know that all angular services are **singletons**. So, you can easily share common logic, data between controller.

**Controller**

```
(function(){

function Controller($scope, Service) {

  //Call our init function
  Service.init();

  //Call our setter
  Service.set(42);

}

angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', Controller);

})();

(function(){

function Controller2($scope, Service) {

  var old = Service.get();
  //Retrieve 42
  console.log(old);

  //Call our init function
  Service.init();

  //Call our setter with new value
  Service.set(++old);

  var newValue = Service.get();

  //Retrieve 43
  console.log(newValue);

}

angular
.module('app')
.controller('ctrl2', Controller2);

})();
```

**Service**

```
(function(){

  function Service() {

    var data;

    function init(){
      console.log('init');
    }

    function get(){
      return data;
    }

    function set(n){
      data = n;
      console.log('Set value : ' + n);
    }

    //Create our object with several method
    var factory = {
      set: set,
      init: init,
      get: get
    };

    return factory;

  }

  angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('Service', Service);

})();
```